# Should you use static methods for helpers in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, formbuilder

I am building a MVC application in PHP, and am creating a Form class to generate a form that you can add elements to. Should I use static methods to generate the form, such as `Form::generate(...)` or in my view class where I declare variables to be used in a view file, should I instantiate the class and use it like `$form->generate(...)`? I have heard using static methods are bad because of testing, but I don't know. Thanks!

Comment: No. You should never use static methods in object oriented code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would agree that static methods have rather fallen out of favour except in certain applications such as:

- Facade pattern, where the static methods hide a more complex API  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern
- Factory pattern, where the static methods are responsible for creating and configuring object instances http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern
- Utility type functions where the class is used almost like a namespace to group together related functions, but the functions themselves are basically procedural (examples could include string, date or price formatting functions)

I would start by creating one Form class that represents your form, and if necessary adding a factory helper which generates an instance of your form.

You might like to take a look at the Symfony form builder, their approach is elegant:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#building-the-form

Comment: Some tools implement the Factory Pattern using a god class, but I don't see why it has to be that way. And that makes me wonder if it's necessary for the Facade Pattern. Finally, a class that exists entirely as a collection of arbitrary helper functions seems like a flaw in the OOP, but again, I don't see why they need to be `explicitly` static.

Comment: Please don't abuse terms. The 'Facade pattern' in Laravel with statics, is nothing to do with the facade pattern in the rest of programming. Also Factories !== static, they should be real objects.

Answer (score 3):

Beside the problem that PHPUnit doesn't support static mocks, the more obvious problem is that of loose coupling and dependency injection. It's completely fine if you have state-independent methods, but to strictly define those methods with the `static` keyword creates a hard dependency on the classname behind the double colon operator. (In fact, it's that hard dependency that makes the PHPUnit problem so tricky.)

Answer (score -1):

That depends, generally static methods wont maintain state, or in other words, you can't use dynamic properties within that class, or instantiate the class ( obviously ).

If you are using them as an OOP way of doing functions it should be fine, in fact I think Laravel uses a lot of them.

http://laravel.com/docs/quick